I'm looking to find a simple way to replace levels of columns by columns with yes/no
I'm looking to find a simple way to do something like the following; from a data frame with the following variables.
 ID        symptom_1               symptom_2                symptom_3
  1          Asthma                   NA                        Fever
  2          Kidney disease          Asthma                       NA
  3          Cough                   Kidney disease             Asthma

I would like to have this:
 ID         Asthma       Kidney disease   Fever   Couugh
  1          yes            no             yes      no
  2          yes            yes            no       no
  3          yes            yes             

The only way I remember is to do something like this (create each variable like:)
dataset$Asthma <- NA

dataset$Asthma[dataset$symptom_1 == "Asthma" | dataset$symptom_2 == "Asthma" | dataset$symptom_3 == "Asthma"] <- "yes"

dataset$Asthma[dataset$symptom_1 != "Asthma" & dataset$symptom_2 != "Asthma" & dataset$symptom_3 != "Asthma"] <- "no"

dataset$Asthma <- as.factor(dataset$Asthma)

Is there a simpler way?
Thank you very much

You could try something like this :
### Packages
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

### Data
df=data.frame(ID=c(1:3),
           symptom_1=c("Asthma","Kidney disease","Cough"),
           symptom_2=c(NA,"Asthma","Kidney disease"),
           symptom_3=c("Fever",NA,"Asthma"))

### Transforming data (unpivot then pivot)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = 2:4) %>%
  mutate (name=1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value,values_from = name) %>%
  select(c(ID,Asthma,`Kidney disease`,Fever,Cough)) %>% 
  mutate(across(-ID,~case_when(is.na(.x)~as.factor("no"),.default = as.factor("yes"))))

Output :
# A tibble: 3 × 5
     ID Asthma `Kidney disease` Fever Cough
  <int> <fct>  <fct>            <fct> <fct>
1     1 yes    no               yes   no   
2     2 yes    yes              no    no   
3     3 yes    yes              no    yes 

